# Problema no login ao clicar botão usando fetch react js?

Tags: javascript, react

Estou com problema ao clicar no botão e fazer login, quando clico no botão ele traz o usuario e senha do banco mas para fazer login e entrar no sistema preciso clicar duas vezes botão, a primeira vez ele não executa `fetch` só segunda vez que faz tudo certinho, o que pode ser.

Segue codigo:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { useHistory, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import * as messages from '../../componentes/toastr';

const Home = () => {

    const [login, setLogin] = useState([]);
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');

    let history = useHistory();

    const getLogin = () => {

        fetch('http://localhost:8080/xxxxxx/login/' + username + "/" + senha)
            .then( async response =>  await response.json())
            .then((res) => setLogin(res)
            ).catch(erro => console.log(erro))

    }

    function btLogin() {

        if (!username) {
            messages.mensagemAlert('O usuario é obrigatório.');
            return false;
        }

        if (!senha) {
            messages.mensagemAlert('O senha é obrigatório.');
            return false;
        }

        getLogin();
 
        if (login.length == 1) {
            entrar();
        }

        if (login.length == 0) {
            messages.mensagemAlert('Senha ou usuário inválido...');
            return false;
        }


    }

    function entrar() {
        history.push('/cards');
    }

    const handleChangeSenha = (event) => {
        setSenha(event.target.value);
        console.log(senha);
    };

    const handleChangeUsername = (event) => {
        setUsername(event.target.value);
    };

    return (

        <div className='bg_image'>
            <div className='img-logo-usina'></div>
            <div className="box">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <form>

                    <div className="inputBox">
                        <input type="text"
                            id="usuario"
                            name="usuario"
                            value={username}
                            onChange={handleChangeUsername}
                        />
                        <label >Usuario</label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="inputBox">
                        <input type="password"
                            id="senha"
                            name="senha"
                            value={senha}
                            onChange={handleChangeSenha}
                        />
                        <label >Senha</label>
                    </div>

                    <div className="d-grid">
                        <button type="button" onClick={btLogin}
                            className="btn btn-success">
                            Entra
                        </button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    )

}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Comment: o código está muito mau elaborado, requisição deveria ser um post, você está passando dados sensiveis na url (Grave), e no meio do botão Login tem um função assicrona sem tratamento, vai dar ruim mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Vou dividir a resposta em duas seções para facilitar o entendimento e separação de problema principal (problema da questão em si) para problemas secundário.

### - Problema principal

Podemos ter duas possíveis teorias para o seu problema:

1. Você não utiliza a sintaxe assíncrona após chamar a função `getLogin()`, e ao verificar a variável `login` o seu estado ainda não foi alterado por conta da demora da requisição.
2. Caso não seja a primeira opção, você está executando a função `entrar()` baseado no estado da variável `login` assim que você faz a alteração deste estado. A alteração de estado ocorre de forma assíncrona e não imediatamente, o que faz com que essa variável possa ter o valor anterior a alteração.

Sugestão: Sugiro que você utilize o `useEffect` para observar alterações no estado `login` e faça a verificação do estado assim que ele for alterado. Seria a mesma lógica que você está utilizando para a validação do login: `login.length == 1`:

```
// imports...

const Home = () => {
  const [login, setLogin] = useState([]);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');

  let history = useHistory();

  const getLogin = () => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/xxxxxx/login/' + username + '/' + senha)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => setLogin(res))
      .catch((erro) => {
        messages.mensagemAlert('Senha ou usuário inválido...')
        console.log(erro)
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (login.length == 1) {
      entrar();
    }
  }, [login])

  function btLogin() {
    if (!username) {
      messages.mensagemAlert('O usuario é obrigatório.');
      return false;
    }

    if (!senha) {
      messages.mensagemAlert('O senha é obrigatório.');
      return false;
    }

    getLogin();
  }

  // resto do componente ...
};

export default withRouter(Home);
```

### - Problema secundário

##### O método `GET` não é adequado para requisições de login por razões de segurança e privacidade:

1. O método `GET` não é adequado por conta desses motivos:

- Incorpora dados na URL como parâmetros, tornando informações de login visíveis e criando riscos de segurança. Além disso, as URLs podem ser armazenadas no histórico do navegador e logs do servidor, expondo informações confidenciais.
- Possui limitação no comprimento da URL, variando conforme navegador e servidor web, dificultando o uso de senhas complexas ou longas para maior segurança no login.
- Dados enviados via `GET` não são criptografados, tornando-se vulneráveis à interceptação e aumentando riscos de roubo de informações confidenciais, como credenciais de login, e violações de privacidade.

Para requisições de login, é recomendado usar o método `POST`, pois ele envia dados no corpo da requisição, mantendo-os ocultos na URL e não apresenta limitações de comprimento. Essa abordagem oferece maior segurança e privacidade em comparação ao método `GET`.

Para utilizar o método `POST` na sua aplicação, o envio deveria ser feito da seguinte forma:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8080/xxxxxx/login/', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username,
    senha,
  }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((res) => setLogin(res))
  .catch((erro) => {
    messages.mensagemAlert('Senha ou usuário inválido...');
    console.log(erro);
  });
```

O back-end também deveria ser alterado para que aceite a requisição de login por um método `POST` na rota de login.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/xxxxxx/login/' + username + '/' + senha` isso não é um problema?

Comment: Pensei em comentar isso após ver o seu comentário, mas achei melhor deixar só a solução para o problema específico do post. Como vocẽ comentou no post, realmente, há várias outras inconsistências no código, mas não sei se seria adequado falar disso na resposta (sou inexperiente por aqui). E tem também  o fato que ele comentou que funciona após o segundo clique no botão, então a api está esperando os dados da maneira como ele está mandando. Mas como você é um usuário mais experiente, deveria ter outras explicações como essa na resposta?

Comment: Filipe a solução com problemas não é solução é cacareco!

Comment: Mas a solução como enviei corrige o problema que ele tem, não outros problemas como o login com GET. A solução não deveria ser para o problema da "assincronicidade" do estado?

Comment: Se você fosse corrigir no seu trabalho, como você faria essa correção? Responder aqui é complicado se vai entender nos votos negativos! se colocou uma solução funcional, talvez, mas, errata no conceito.

Comment: Entendi, claro, faria uma correção o código de uma maneira mais "completa". Mas acabei não pensando desta forma aqui no SO. Ou seja, deveria então corrigir o código de uma maneira geral e explicar o motivo. Muito obrigado pelo toque. Eu tava pensando de uma forma mais centrada na resolução do problema da questão.